# Javascript return statement doesn't stop rest of function from completing

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

I am using Docuware's API to staple (merge) documents together. I have written my question as simple as I can so people with no Docuware knowledge should be able to understand.

So in my main function, I call another function and check the return value of the called function. If the value equals zero, it should return null - meaning the rest of the function should not run.

```
const lastStored = await searchDocument("Invoice", ORDER_NUMBER = '', cookie)
console.log("Full id func: " + id)
console.log("id[0]: " + id[0])

if (lastStored[0] === 0) {
    console.log("id[0]: " + id[0])
    return null;
};
```

I am getting weird errors with my code, so I have a lot of console.logs. Here are the console.logs when the code successfully works.

```
 cookie set
 Document is Invoice (Invoice)
 Invoice order #: ORD83001
 Current ID: 52724 Order #: ORD83001
 cookie set
 Document is DELIVERY SLIP (DELIVERY SLIP)
 Invoice order #: ORD83001
 DELIVERY SLIP Doc ID: 52553
 Current ID: 52553 Order #: ORD83001
 Full id func: 52553,ORD83001
 id[0]: 52553
 New Tray Doc ID: 1410
 Document's successfully merged.
```

Now, with the error, the console.logs are:

```
 //.....
 Current ID: 0 Order #: ORD83009
 Full id func: 0,ORD83009
 id[0]: 0
 id[0]: 0
 Document's successfully merged.
```

The thing about this error, is that if id[0] was truly zero, then the document's wouldn't be able to be merged. But the documents ARE merged if I look at them. So why is my code returning 0, even INSIDE my if statement, yet continues to run?

Is it some sort of timing issue? Like id[0] === 0 but .00000001 seconds later it gets updated so the return null doesn't follow through?

Comment: The message "Document's successfully merged" is certainly produced by *another* execution context of that function -- not the one that had `id[0]` equal to 0. I guess you have more `await` expression further down the function body, and each of those can allow another function context to get restored and continue its execution.

Comment: "Document's successfully merged" is a console.log AFTER the if statement in the main function. From my understand, if the if statement gets triggered, none of the rest of the code in the main function should run. You are right, there are more await expressions, but since its after the if statement, should it basically stop all code after?

Comment: Please reread my comment. You are right that when `return` is executed that no other code of that function is executed for **that execution context**. But you should realise that every `await` suspends one of the function's execution contexts, but those will eventually be restored and be responsible for the further execution of code in that function, which may give the *impression* that the `return` was not executed, but this code is executed by a **different** execution context.

Comment: Huh. To be honest, I've never heard of execution content before. I will need to look into that to learn more and see how I can fix this.

Comment: You sure you're not inside a callback or other secondary function when you `return`?  Can't tell with what you have posted above.

Comment: No, it's inside my main function. async function mergeDocument () {
  const cookie = await setCookie();
  const lastStored = await searchDocument("Invoice", ORDER_NUMBER = '', cookie)
  if (lastStored[0] === 0) {

    return null;
  }; ............} The "Document's successfully merged" is in ANOTHER function, but its called at the very end of the main function

Comment: The thing is that you have at least one `await` between that `return null` and the output of "Document's successfully merged.". Every `await` is a point in your code where a suspended execution can *later* **resume** execution, giving you the wrong impression that it is the **same** execution that executed the `return null`. This is a wrong conclusion. You can clarify this for yourself, by assigning a unique value to a local variable at the top of your function, and always output the value of that variable with every output you do in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have `await` between the part of the code where you `return null` and where the output of "Document's successfully merged" is made.

Every `await` is a point in your code where an execution context is *suspended*. Depending on the awaited promise, there will be some time in the future where the suspended execution will be *resumed* again. This can lead to surprising sequences of output.

Here is a simple demo of this effect. Note how the output in the `if` block is followed by the output below it. It would be wrong to conclude that the `return` somehow didn't "work". It did, but there was another execution of this function which was suspended (as waiting for a promise to resolve) and got restored only to make that final output:

```js
const something = i => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, i * 1000));

async function demo(i) {
    console.log("test the value of i");
    if (i == 1) {
        console.log("i is one, so we exit");
        return null;
    }
    await something(i);
    console.log("performed the action");
}

demo(0);
demo(1);
```

Comment: Okay, so I kinda understand it a bit better now. Like I mentioned, I'm having weird errors, which is why I'm just trying to figure out where it errors out in the first place. Does this mean I can just disregard this, and assume the errors happen elsewhere in the code?

Comment: I cannot judge that. I have only explained why this is expected behaviour. Whether your overall logic is correct depends on factors outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was hoping this error could help me resolve my code not working all the time. I'm still entry level, and this code is for my company, but they have no software engineers on payroll, so I have no one to ask. Thank you for helping out with this part, though! :)